# Can the RequireJS optimiser tool used without Node.js?

Tags: node.js, requirejs

Is it possible to use anything other than Node.js to run `r.js` to minimize the amount of HTTP request that are made using RequireJS. I have read a lot of websites and tutorials but still everything is explained using Node.

I would appreciate a working example if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. The [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#requirements) states:

> The optimizer can be run using Node, Java with Rhino or Nashorn, or in the browser.

The [README](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js) for `r.js` contains examples of how to use it with Rhino or Nashorn. With Nashorn, quoting from the documentation:

> ```
> jjs -scripting path/to/r.js -- [r.js command line arguments here]
> ```

With Rhino:

```
java -classpath path/to/rhino/js.jar:path/to/closure/compiler.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main r.js [r.js command line arguments here]
```

(The documentation does not have `[r.js command line arguments here]` but reading the whole documentation implies that it is how it works.)

Comment: it says or in the browser what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I'm reporting what the documentation says. I've not used `r.js` in the browser. Unfortunately the documentation is not very detailed about how you'd use in the browser. There's one example [here](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/tests/browser/r.html).